# Update existing XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, updatexml

I tried to update this small xml example file without success.
It is not giving me any error but the file remains unchanged.
Any ideas ?

Thanks

XML Sample:

```
<test>
  <user>John Doe</user>
  <user>Jane Doe</user>
</test>
```

C# Code

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("../../../test.xml");

    XmlNode sNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/test/user");
    XmlAttribute users = sNode.Attributes["user"];

    if (users != null)
    {             
            string currentValue = users.Value;            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
            {
            users.Value = "Thomas";
            }
    }
    doc.Save("../../../test1.xml");
```

Comment: `sNode.Attributes["user"]` your xml doesn't contain a user attribute

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed the value inside a node:

```
        XmlNode node= _doc.SelectSingleNode("test/user[1]"); // [index of user node]
        node.InnerText = value;
        _doc.Save(@"path");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works now perfectly:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("../../../test.xml");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("test/user[1]"); // [index of user node]
node.InnerText = "thomas";

doc.Save("../../../test1.xml");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your user node doesn't have any attribute in your XML file :

So `users` is null here :

```
 XmlAttribute users = sNode.Attributes["user"];
```

You should test if sNode != null

```
 if (sNode != null){
    ....
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that I don`t have an attribute there, but the solution from Timon Post was what I was looking for and it works perfectly.